# Write a regex to match until the final forward slash before the first equal sign

Tags: regex

Here's a fun regex problem.  Write one regex that will get the results for group one as "path/to/file" for the following example strings:

1. path/to/file/foo=1/bar.txt
2. path/to/file/foo=1/bar=2/baz.txt
3. path/to/file/foo.txt

So to explain, I want to match up to the final forward slash before the first occurrence of an '='.

I was able to match a regex with the example string one `(^.*)\/(.*)=` but it captures path/to/file/foo=1 from example string 2 -- this is not as intended, I do not want to see the part of the path with the '='.

I can use `(^.*)\/(.*)=(.*)=` to solve example 2, but this doesn't scale to the other examples.

Example 3 is easy enough to capture with `(^.*)\/`  Being able to match string 3 is a nice to have, but I have a way of easily solving for this in my code.

Thanks for your help and I look forward to learning more about regex.

Comment: If you're parsing URLs, then use the URL parser that's built in to your language.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this regex,

```
^([^=]+)\/
```

This will match everything except `=` and will stop the match as soon as it finds a `/` and will capture the contents in group one as you want.

**[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2sfhnY/1)**